# Python - bs4 - webscraping - Can not get the whole URL from the website

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to webscrape the URL link of an ad from a website.
I have following code in jupyter notebook

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
link = "https://www.marktplaats.nl/l/auto-s/bmw/p/1/"
data = requests.get(link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.content,"html.parser")
​
car1 = soup.findAll('li',{'class':'mp-Listing mp-Listing--list-item'})[0]
​
car1.a['href']
```

When I run this code i get the following url:

```
'/a/auto-s/bmw/a1322384400-bmw-x5-s-drive-executive-automaat-leder-navigatie-nr-038.html'
```

I think this is a relative URL and not the full URL.
When I inspect the page I do see this URL, but when I put my mouse on it I get to see the whole URL.
I would like to scrape the whole URL, can anyone help me?

I have added two images one shows the shortend URL and the other shows the full URL

Shortened URL image:
[image]

Full URL image:
[image]

Comment: That is not a relative URL but an absolute one (as it starts from the root folder by starting with a forward slash). To get the full url just append the domain name in front so `"https://www.martkplaats.nl" + car1.a['href']`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. This has solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Putting my answer a comment so the question can be marked as answered :). That is not a relative URL but an absolute one (as it starts from the root folder by starting with a forward slash). To get the full url just append the domain name in front so "https://www.martkplaats.nl" + car1.a['href']

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Python 3, you can use [`urllib.parse.urljoin()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urljoin) to *join* the base URL in `link` and the path from `car1.a['href']`.

`car1.a['href']` is a *relative* path since *absolute URIs* start with the protocol/scheme or with a double slash `//`.

> If *url* is an absolute URL (that is, starting with `//` or `scheme://` ), ...

The starting single `/` in `/a/auto-s/...` indicates that the link is ***relative to the root*** of the host and not from the current path of the page on which you see it. (The current page's path is `/l/auto-s/bmw/p/1/`.)

Putting tha together:

```
>>> import urllib
>>>
>>> car_url = urllib.parse.urljoin(link, car1.a['href'])
>>> car_url
'https://www.marktplaats.nl/a/auto-s/bmw/a1322384400-bmw-x5-s-drive-executive-automaat-leder-navigatie-nr-038.html'
>>>
>>> car_page = requests.get(car_url).content
>>> car_soup = BeautifulSoup(car_page, 'html.parser')
>>> car_soup.title.text
'≥ BMW X5 S-Drive Executive Automaat Leder Navigatie - Nr 038 - BMW - Marktplaats.nl'
>>>
```